# Is there any way to cancel the timed out approval flow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, ms-flow

Is there any way to cancel the Timed out approval. In my Scenario the approval will timeout when there is no response from the assigned person.
I am resending the approval once again, but the previous approval was still there in the mail.
Is there any way to cancel the timedout apporoval using flow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the action "Start and wait for an approval" in flow, currently there is no such way to cancel the time out approval.

If you use actions like "Create an approval" or "Wait for an approval", we could use "Update a row" action to cancel the approval request by changing the record in Dataverse.

[image]

For detailed information, please refer to:

https://www.imenos.com/en/power-platform/cancel-and-escalate-power-automate-approval-request/

Comment: Is there some more official/authoritative documentation about how to update an Approval Request programmatically via Power Automate flow?  I've been searching for hours and it's very hard to find relevant results.  I came across one other article that warned about the dangers of NOT defining the field 'Approval Stage Key' and says `This is not mandatory but will make the record align with other records = avoiding mess in DataBase`.   It sounds like you could easily mess things up and I'd like an authoritative solution.  https://365corner.pl/2020/11/13/timeout-in-power-automate-approval/

Comment: I get this error on the `Update a row` action:  Principal user (Id=*****-*****-*****-*****-*****, type=8, roleCount=6, privilegeCount=1256, accessMode=0, MetadataCachePrivilegesCount=4581, businessUnitId=*****-*****-*****-*****-*****), is missing prvWritemsdyn_flow_approval privilege (Id=*****-*****-*****-*****-*****) on OTC=10178 for entity 'msdyn_flow_approval' (LocalizedName='Approval'). context.Caller=*****-*****-*****-*****-*****. Consider adding missed privilege to one of the principal (user/team) roles.

Comment: Possible solution to error is here, but I can't test it because I am not 'adminy' enough to grant myself those permissions:  https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Error-when-trying-to-cancel-an-Approval-record/td-p/1308257

Comment: For reference, it turns out I was able to grant the account running the flow the 'Approvals Administrator' role through a process similar to that described in this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWi5j06eC0I